# How to perform Two Operation in main queue

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, queue

I have two tasks that need to perform on main queue but the main queue is serial so I need some help.

1. I am showing a progress bar which will be spinning until task not finished
2. The task is itself needs to perform on the main thread because it has to access frames of view and drawing the images as well.

So now the problem is when the main queue is executing the tasks it pauses the progress view.

and I can not execute the task in the background because it needs to be done in main queue

Please suggest

Comment: Whoever downvoted please add the reason

Answer (score 1):

1. You should never perform lengthy tasks on the main thread.
2. You can do drawing in the background, as long as it doesn't affect visible views.
3. Once the background task is done, switch back to main thread to present the results on screen, and remove the activity indicator.

Comment: Nope Xcode starts giving me a warning if I access any view from background thread

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Background thread should have nothing to do with views. If you want to draw, draw in an image buffer, and when done update the view inside DispatchQueue.main.async.